# cygwin rm command fails with the following error

Tags: cygwin

```
c:\>rm -rf foldername
```

> rm: failed to get attributes of `/': No such file or directory

Why does this fail? This happens on the Win XP OS.

Comment: It looks to me like your Cygwin installation got messed up somehow.  Have you tried nuking Cygwin and reinstalling it?